# PHP DOMDocument getElementsByTagname?

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

This is driving me bonkers... I just want to add another `img` node.

```
$xml = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gallery>
    <album tnPath="tn/" lgPath="imm/"  fsPath="iml/" >
    <img src="004.jpg" caption="4th caption" />
    <img src="005.jpg" caption="5th caption" />
    <img src="006.jpg" caption="6th caption" />
</album>
</gallery>
XML;

$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->loadXML($xml);

$album = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagname('album')[0];
// Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/admin/tests/DOMDoc.php  on line 17
$album = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagname('album');
// Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMNodeList::appendChild() in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/admin/tests/DOMDoc.php on line 19

$newImg = $xmlDoc->createElement("img");
$album->appendChild($newImg);

print $xmlDoc->saveXML();
```

Error:

Comment: `$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagname('album')[0];` now works in PHP7 :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName doesn't return an array, it returns a [DOMNodeList](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php). You need to use the `item` method to access its items:

```
$album = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagname('album')->item(0);
```

Comment: mmmm: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type DOMNodeList as array in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/admin/tests/DOMDoc.php  on line 18

Comment: Hooray!! Thanks so much Matti.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/admin/tests/DOMDoc.php  on line 17
```

you cant do this in php

```
$album = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagname('album')[0];
```

you have to do this

```
$albumList = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagname('album');
$album = $albumList[0];
```

**EDIT:** getElementsByTagname returns an object so you can do this (above code is incorrect)...

```
$album = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagname('album')->item(0);
```

This error....

```
// Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMNodeList::appendChild() in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/admin/tests/DOMDoc.php on line 19
```

DOMNodeList doesnt have an appendChild method. DOMNode does.