# How to find and get attribute from XML file

Tags: php, xml

How can I find and get currency for 'USD', 'GBP' and 'EUR' from XML file using PHP?

My XML file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-2"?>
<tabela_kursow typ="A" uid="13a033">
   <numer_tabeli>033/A/NBP/2013</numer_tabeli>
   <data_publikacji>2013-02-15</data_publikacji>
   <pozycja>
      <nazwa_waluty>bat (Tajlandia)</nazwa_waluty>
      <przelicznik>1</przelicznik>
      <kod_waluty>THB</kod_waluty>
      <kurs_sredni>0,1052</kurs_sredni>
   </pozycja>
   <pozycja>
      <nazwa_waluty>dolar amerykański</nazwa_waluty>
      <przelicznik>1</przelicznik>
      <kod_waluty>USD</kod_waluty>
      <kurs_sredni>3,1398</kurs_sredni>
   </pozycja>
```

File comes from here: [Polish National Bank](http://www.nbp.pl/kursy/xml/LastA.xml)

I donwload file and save it on my server:

```
$basedir = "/mypath/www/dirname";

$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement("http://www.nbp.pl/kursy/xml/LastA.xml", null, true);

file_put_contents($basedir."/subdirname/output.xml", $sxe->asXML());
```

Using downloaded XML file how to get **`<kurs_sredni>`** for only `<kod_waluty>` = USD, EUR, GBP?

Comment: I'm not sure you can do it with XPath. But you can put all the rates to an array together with the corresponding currency and then use the ones you need.

Comment: Using 
$tabela_kursow = new SimpleXMLElement($basedir."/subdirname/output.xml", null, true);
echo "Currency: ".$tabela_kursow->pozycja[1]->kurs_sredni;
is quite easy to get value of kurs_sredni, but how to find/get/know which pozycja[] it is?

Comment: user1641443 wrote exactly what I meant :) You iterate through all `pozycja` and check the currency and the exchange rate. If the currency is one you need you save the exchange rate for later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do this by iterating over all elements, check if the current element matches your criteria and you then extract the data interested in:

```
$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement("http://www.nbp.pl/kursy/xml/LastA.xml", null, true);

$accept = array_flip(explode(',', 'USD,EUR,GBP'));

foreach($sxe->pozycja as $pozycja)
{
    $currency = (string) $pozycja->kod_waluty;
    if (isset($accept[$currency])) {
        $accept[$currency] = (string) $pozycja->kurs_sredni;
    }
}

print_r($accept);
```

This gives you:

```
Array
(
    [USD] => 3,1398
    [EUR] => 4,1852
    [GBP] => 4,8620
)
```

If you only want to delete XML elements and save the XML again (as you suggest in your question), you don't need to filter the data at all. Just store the XML unfiltered, it's not such a large file of any kind.

Comment: As you wrote, I will store original XML file, simple and clear.

Answer (score 1):

you can read with something like this. This is not complete code, please fill gaps:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load( $pathFileName );

$pozycjas = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "pozycja" );

foreach($pozycjas as $eachPozycja)
{
  //readef fields
  $kod_waluty = $eachPozycja->getElementsByTagName( "kod_waluty " )->item(0)->nodeValue;

  if($kod_waluty is value u want)
       //read and store kurs_sredni
       $kurs_sredni= $eachPozycja->getElementsByTagName( "kurs_sredni" )->item(0)->nodeValue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I used: _$doc->loadXML(file_get_contents($pathFileName));_
but now I got error: _Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMDocument::getElementByTagName() in... line 65_
And the line 65 is: _$pozycjas = $doc->getElementByTagName( "pozycja" );_

Comment: check thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845908/php-domdocument-getelementsbytagname