# Same PHP script runs differently on 2 machines

Tags: php, xml, laravel, dom

How is it possible that the same PHP script I'm using for parsing an XML file is running differently on two different machines?
So, on my VM (Laravel Homestead, running PHP 5.6.11) the script is running as it should, but when I transfer it to a web hosting, it throws an "Cannot use object of type DOMNodeList as array" error.
The script in question is [here](http://pastebin.com/xbBP3Q8y), and error is thrown on the line 77, but the variable it's referring to is this:

```
$choices = $v->getElementsByTagName('choice');
```

Could it be the PHP version or something else? The web hosting is running PHP 5.5

Screenshot of the error:
[image]

Comment: Seems that you are misinterpreting the result of getElementsByTagName, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845908/php-domdocument-getelementsbytagname

Comment: Try changing the line of code you mentioned to `$choices = iterator_to_array($v->getElementsByTagName('choice'));`

Answer (score 0):

As I was suspecting, after the admins switched to version 5.6.12, everything started working as it should. No error whatsoever.